# Cloud composer running containr on compute

Tags: google-cloud-composer

How can I launch a compute instance and deploy a container on it?
I can see that there is a python operator but to my understanding that will run the script in a pre-made container on the Airflow workers rather than on an external instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used bash operator in order to create a compute instance with a VM.

```
create_compute_instance = bash_operator.BashOperator(
    task_id='create_compute',
    bash_command='gcloud beta compute instances create-with-container airflow-vm --zone us-central1-a \
 --container-image gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/nginx1:1.12')
```

[Running container on VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#deploying_a_container_on_a_new_vm_instance)